# Does ANSI SQL standard inlcude FORALL predicate?

Tags: sql-standard

I need to get all predicate of SQL (that was included in ANSI standard any version). Some databases (Oracle) have `FORALL` predicate. But I am not sure if that is part of the SQL specifications.

Does it include this predicate?

P.S. Please, do not send me to the standard. My English is not so good to I can get it otherwise I wouldn't ask it here.

Comment: According to Postgres docs: No https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: `FORALL` seems to be a part of [PL/SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL), which is Oracle's procedural language extension to SQL.

Comment: Seems you are right, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Searching through a copy (of a draft) of the 2011 SQL Standard, there is no mention at all of a `FORALL` keyword.

Neither in the main document ("Part 2: Foundation (SQL/Foundation)") which describes the core SQL language nor in the extensions document ("Part 4: Persistent Stored Modules (SQL/PSM)") which describes persistent routines and server modules. There are several control and repeat structures and keywords (`DO`, `ITERATE`, `FOR`, `LOOP`, `WHILE`, `REPEAT`) but not `FORALL`.

Postgres docs also have an extensive list of [SQL Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) (taken from the 92, 2008 and 2011 versions of the standard). No mention of `FORALL` there either.

`FORALL` seems to be a keyword only in Oracle's procedural language extension to SQL.